# Error displaying days in the calendar for a specific month System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.get_Item(Tkey key)

Tags: c#

Following on from my earlier question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140755/system-collections-generic-keynotfoundexception-in-mscorlib-dll-error-in-calend for some context, I have a problem with displaying days in the calendar, it only happens for some months, I'm currently showing the error in the try cath block = "**System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item (Tkey key)**" in the RenderMonthCalendar method on this line :

```
Point point = _calendarDays[i];
```

I've been looking for some solutions on the Internet, and how do I understand I need to convert it into an array?
This way I made a method, so I could now include this guy in it?

```
internal static KeyValuePair<int, Point>[] Convert(IDictionary<int, Point> from)
            {
                return from.ToArray();
            }
```

This is part of anyone from the method in which my calendar shoots.

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, Point> _calendarDays;
_calendarDays = new Dictionary<int, Point>();
        private void RenderMonthCalendar(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            _calendarDays.Clear();
            _calendarEvents.Clear();
            var bmp = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
            g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
            SizeF sunSize = g.MeasureString("Sonntag", _dayOfWeekFont);
            SizeF monSize = g.MeasureString("Montag", _dayOfWeekFont);
            SizeF tueSize = g.MeasureString("Dienstag", _dayOfWeekFont);
            SizeF wedSize = g.MeasureString("Mittwoch", _dayOfWeekFont);
            SizeF thuSize = g.MeasureString("Donnerstag", _dayOfWeekFont);
            SizeF friSize = g.MeasureString("Freitag", _dayOfWeekFont);
            SizeF satSize = g.MeasureString("Samstag", _dayOfWeekFont);
            SizeF dateHeaderSize = g.MeasureString(
                _calendarDate.ToString("MMMM") + " " + _calendarDate.Year.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")), _dateHeaderFont);
            int headerSpacing = Max(sunSize.Height, monSize.Height, tueSize.Height, wedSize.Height, thuSize.Height, friSize.Height,
                          satSize.Height) + 5;
            int controlsSpacing = ((!_showTodayButton) && (!_showDateInHeader) && (!_showArrowControls)) ? 0 : 30;
            int cellWidth = (ClientSize.Width - MarginSize * 2) / 7;
            int numWeeks = NumberOfWeeks(_calendarDate.Year, _calendarDate.Month);
            int cellHeight = (ClientSize.Height - MarginSize * 2 - headerSpacing - controlsSpacing) / numWeeks;
            int xStart = MarginSize;
            int yStart = MarginSize;
            DayOfWeek startWeekEnum = new DateTime(_calendarDate.Year, _calendarDate.Month, 1).DayOfWeek;
            //   int startWeek = ((int)startWeekEnum) +1;
            int startWeek = ((int)startWeekEnum);
            if (startWeek == 0) startWeek = 7;
            int rogueDays = startWeek - 1;

            yStart += headerSpacing + controlsSpacing;

            int counter = 1;
            int counter2 = 1;

            bool first = false;
            bool first2 = false;

            _btnToday.Location = new Point(MarginSize, MarginSize);

            for (int y = 0; y < numWeeks; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
                {
                    if (rogueDays == 0 && counter <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(_calendarDate.Year, _calendarDate.Month))
                    {
                        if (!_calendarDays.ContainsKey(counter))
                            _calendarDays.Add(counter, new Point(xStart, (int)(yStart + 2f + g.MeasureString(counter.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")), _daysFont).Height)));

                        if (_calendarDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && _calendarDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                         && counter == DateTime.Now.Day && _highlightCurrentDay)
                        {
                            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(234, 234, 234)), xStart, yStart, cellWidth, cellHeight);
                        }

                        if (first == false)
                        {
                            first = true;
                            if (_calendarDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && _calendarDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                         && counter == DateTime.Now.Day)
                            {
                                g.DrawString(
                                    _calendarDate.ToString("MMM") + " " + counter.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")),
                                    _todayFont, Brushes.Black, xStart + 5, yStart + 2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                g.DrawString(
                                    _calendarDate.ToString("MMM") + " " + counter.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")),
                                    _daysFont, Brushes.Black, xStart + 5, yStart + 2);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (_calendarDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && _calendarDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                         && counter == DateTime.Now.Day)
                            {
                                g.DrawString(counter.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")), _todayFont, Brushes.Black, xStart + 5, yStart + 2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                g.DrawString(counter.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")), _daysFont, Brushes.Black, xStart + 5, yStart + 2);
                            }
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else if (rogueDays > 0)
                    {
                        int dm =
                            DateTime.DaysInMonth(_calendarDate.AddMonths(-1).Year, _calendarDate.AddMonths(-1).Month) -
                            rogueDays + 1;
                        g.DrawString(dm.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")), _daysFont, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, 170, 170)), xStart + 5, yStart + 2);
                        rogueDays--;
                    }

                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, xStart, yStart, cellWidth, cellHeight);
                    if (rogueDays == 0 && counter > DateTime.DaysInMonth(_calendarDate.Year, _calendarDate.Month))
                    {
                        if (first2 == false)
                            first2 = true;
                        else
                        {
                            if (counter2 == 1)
                            {
                                g.DrawString(_calendarDate.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMM") + " " + counter2.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")), _daysFont,
                                             new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, 170, 170)), xStart + 5, yStart + 2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                g.DrawString(counter2.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")), _daysFont,
                                             new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, 170, 170)), xStart + 5, yStart + 2);
                            }
                            counter2++;
                        }
                    }
                    xStart += cellWidth;
                }
                xStart = MarginSize;
                yStart += cellHeight;
            }
            xStart = MarginSize + ((cellWidth - (int)sunSize.Width) / 2);
            yStart = MarginSize + controlsSpacing;

            g.DrawString("Montag", _dayOfWeekFont, Brushes.Black, xStart, yStart);

            xStart = MarginSize + ((cellWidth - (int)monSize.Width) / 2) + cellWidth;
            g.DrawString("Dienstag", _dayOfWeekFont, Brushes.Black, xStart, yStart);

            xStart = MarginSize + ((cellWidth - (int)tueSize.Width) / 2) + cellWidth * 2;
            g.DrawString("Mittwoch", _dayOfWeekFont, Brushes.Black, xStart, yStart);

            xStart = MarginSize + ((cellWidth - (int)wedSize.Width) / 2) + cellWidth * 3;
            g.DrawString("Donnerstag", _dayOfWeekFont, Brushes.Black, xStart, yStart);

            xStart = MarginSize + ((cellWidth - (int)thuSize.Width) / 2) + cellWidth * 4;
            g.DrawString("Freitag", _dayOfWeekFont, Brushes.Black, xStart, yStart);

            xStart = MarginSize + ((cellWidth - (int)friSize.Width) / 2) + cellWidth * 5;
            g.DrawString("Samstag", _dayOfWeekFont, Brushes.Black, xStart, yStart);

            xStart = MarginSize + ((cellWidth - (int)satSize.Width) / 2) + cellWidth * 6;
            g.DrawString("Sonntag", _dayOfWeekFont, Brushes.Black, xStart, yStart);

            if (_showDateInHeader)
            {
                var dutchCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
                g.DrawString(
                    _calendarDate.ToString("MMMM", dutchCulture) + " " + _calendarDate.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    _dateHeaderFont, Brushes.Black, ClientSize.Width - MarginSize - dateHeaderSize.Width,
                    MarginSize);
            }
            _events.Sort(new EventComparer());
            try
            { 
                for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(_calendarDate.Year, _calendarDate.Month); i++)
                {
                    int renderOffsetY = 0;

                    foreach (IEvent v in _events)
                    {
                        var dt = new DateTime(_calendarDate.Year, _calendarDate.Month, i, 23, 59, _calendarDate.Second);
                        if (NeedsRendering(v, dt))
                        {
                            int alpha = 255;
                            if (!v.Enabled && _dimDisabledEvents)
                                alpha = 64;
                            Color alphaColor = Color.FromArgb(alpha, v.EventColor.R, v.EventColor.G, v.EventColor.B);

                            int offsetY = renderOffsetY;
                            Region r = g.Clip;
                            Point point = _calendarDays[i];//hier I get a bug in the catch block = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item (Tkey key)" 
                            SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(v.EventText, v.EventFont);
                            int yy = point.Y - 1;
                            int xx = ((cellWidth - (int)sz.Width) / 2) + point.X;

                            if (sz.Width > cellWidth)
                                xx = point.X;
                            if (renderOffsetY + sz.Height > cellHeight - 10)
                                continue;
                            g.Clip = new Region(new Rectangle(point.X + 1, point.Y + offsetY, cellWidth - 1, (int)sz.Height));
                            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(alphaColor), point.X + 1, point.Y + offsetY, cellWidth - 1, sz.Height);
                            if (!v.Enabled && _showDashedBorderOnDisabledEvents)
                            {
                                var p = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0))) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash };
                                g.DrawRectangle(p, point.X + 1, point.Y + offsetY, cellWidth - 2, sz.Height - 1);
                            }
                            g.DrawString(v.EventText, v.EventFont, new SolidBrush(v.EventTextColor), xx, yy + offsetY);
                            g.Clip = r;

                            var ev = new CalendarEvent
                            {
                                EventArea =
                                    new Rectangle(point.X + 1, point.Y + offsetY, cellWidth - 1,
                                                  (int)sz.Height),
                                Event = v,
                                Date = dt
                            };

                            _calendarEvents.Add(ev);
                            renderOffsetY += (int)sz.Height + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            _rectangles.Clear();

            g.Dispose();
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
            bmp.Dispose();
        }
```

on daily events, I miss a calendar and I get a bug in the catch block = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item (Tkey key)", please how can I rescue it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication120
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(2019, i, 1);
                DateTime firstMondayOfMonth = FirstMonday(2019, i);

                Console.WriteLine("Month {0}, First Day of Month {1}, First Monday {2}", i,firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek.ToString(), firstMondayOfMonth);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static DateTime FirstMonday(int year, int month)
        {
            DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek;
            int addDays = (DayOfWeek.Monday - dayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

            return firstDayOfMonth.AddDays(addDays);

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help me, but how can I integrate this code into my method? This is true, but I work with the calendar https://www.codeproject.com/articles/378900/calendar-net and I need to edit it

Comment: You have to figure out how to modify your code.  I can't tell if the issue is when you are adding events or some place else in the code.  My code is getting first Monday of the Month given the Year and Month.